# How do I sort dictionary by Key in Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, key

I need to sort below dictionary and print first five items from sorted dictionary:

```
station_dict_platOne = {'6': 'Daly City', '12': 'Daly City', '19': 'Daly City', 'Leaving': 'Millbrae', '16': 'SF Airport', '28': 'Millbrae', '10': 'SF Airport', '22': 'SF Airport'}
```

I am using this code:

```
j=0
for i in sorted(station_dict_platOne):
        if j<5:
        print(i+" "+"min", station_dict_platOne[i])
        j = j+1
```

But, I am getting below output and this is not the correct output.

```
10 min SF Airport
12 min Daly City
16 min SF Airport
19 min Daly City
22 min SF Airport
```

Comment: It looks right to me "10" comes before "6" in text comparisons. Did you want to cast the keys to int?

Comment: Yes, I need it to be sorted in comparison to their integer value

Comment: I tried this:     for i in sorted(station_dict_platOne, key=lambda t: int(t[0])):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'L'

Comment: @KennyOstrom the suggested link contain quite different question than what I have asked.

Comment: yes, because 'Leaving' can not be turned into a number. Either use another number (e.g. -1 if you want it on first place), or remove it from the dict before iteration. You also can hand another lambda (lambda t: int(t) if t != 'Leaving' else math.inf)

Comment: you can define a more robust conversion function than just key=lambda int, but that's a minor implementation detail. Do you need it reopened for help on the key function? It can just return 0 for 'Leaving' and maybe other special keywords. (but still fundamentally the same issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is probably not in the code, but in the typing:
The keys are strings (texts) and not ints (numbers), so `'10' < '6' == True`.

Either use numbers for keys (just `6: 'Daly City'`, without the quotation marks) or parse them while ordering (call `sorted(station_dict_platOne, key=lambda t: int(t))` in the for-loop).

Note: both ways will fail with your 'Leaving' key. You have to filter it, or use some special case!

Comment: I tired this:  for i in sorted(station_dict_platOne, key=lambda t: int(t[0])):
                             if j<5:
                                print(i+" "+"min", station_dict_platOne[i])
                                j = j+1

Comment: It is not working

Comment: 1 min Millbrae
12 min Millbrae
15 min Millbrae
10 min SF Airport
19 min SF Airport
{'3': 'Daly City', '6': 'Daly City', '8': 'Daly City', '1': 'Millbrae', '12': 'Millbrae', '15': 'Millbrae', '10': 'SF Airport', '19': 'SF Airport', '34': 'SF Airport'}

Comment: Damn. Sorry, fixed it. I always forget that python iterates over keys of a dict. Try `lambda t: int(t)` instead `t[0]`

Comment: Don't forget, It doesn't have to be a lambda. You can define a function and have it return special values for known keywords, like "Leaving" -> 0, or maybe max-int for other non-integer values.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the 'Leaving' key you can do this:

```
s = {6: 'Daly City', 12: 'Daly City', 19: 'Daly City',
     16: 'SF Airport', 28: 'Millbrae', 10: 'SF Airport', 22: 'SF Airport'}

for k in sorted(s):
    print(k, s[k])
```

which outputs:

```
6 Daly City
10 SF Airport
12 Daly City
16 SF Airport
19 Daly City
22 SF Airport
28 Millbrae
```

I don't know if that's what you are looking for

Comment: Also, I forgot you also have to change the keys from string type to int.

Comment: what is the best way to perform this: string type to int

Comment: If s is your dict you can do s=dict(zip(map(lambda x: int(x), s.keys()), s.values()))